# How can I serve Html pages in twisted/python?

Tags: python, twisted

My twisted/python webservice runs on port 8080. I have client.html page for to be visible for initial GET request fro port 8080. (ie: localhost:8080)
From that html I have linked other html pages.
How can I register a folder and provide that link in my client html page to open those linked html pages?

my twisted app is;

```
class Root(resource.Resource):
    isLeaf = False
    responseContent = "Lob Cache"

    def getChild(self, name, request):
        return self

    def render_GET(self, request):
        return self.returnResponse(request)

    def render_POST(self, request):
        return self.returnResponse(request)

    def returnResponse(self, request):
        f = open('clients.html', 'r')
        request.setHeader(b"content-type", b"text/html")
        return f.read()
   ....
site = Root()
site.putChild('cache', NetworkCacheManager())
endpoints.serverFromString(reactor, "tcp:port=8080:interface=0.0.0.0").listen(server.Site(site))
reactor.run()
```

Currently my html pages and python script is in same folder location.

I want to link  other pages like; `<a href="http://localhost:8080/clientSiteinfo.html`

I can put other html pages in my webserver( apache webserver, but im getting cross domain issues)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for this. I
created a `HTML` folder and copied all `HTML` files inside that and registered a path like:

```
site.putChild("doc", static.File("/Users/ratha/projects/TestPython/com/lob/html"))
```

Then accessing my `HTML` files as

```
<a href="http://localhost:8080/doc/clientSiteinfo.html></a>
```